# Is overflow of an unsigned bit field guaranteed to wrap-around?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, integer-overflow, bit-fields

#### Details

The [reference for bit fields at cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) presents the following example:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> struct S {
>  // three-bit unsigned field,
>  // allowed values are 0...7
>  unsigned int b : 3;
> };
> int main()
> {
>     S s = {7};
>     ++s.b; // unsigned overflow (guaranteed wrap-around)
>     std::cout << s.b << '\n'; // output: 0
> }
> ```

Emphasis on the *guaranteed wrap-around* comment.

However, [WG21 CWG Issue 1816](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1816) describe some possible issues with unclear specification of bit field values, and [[expr.post.incr]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#incr-1) in the latest standard draft states:

> The value of a postfix ++ expression is the value of its operand. ...
>
> If the operand is a bit-field that cannot represent the incremented value, the resulting value of the bit-field is implementation-defined.

I'm unsure, however, if this applies also for wrap-around of unsigned bit fields.

#### Question

- Is overflow of an unsigned bit field guaranteed to wrap-around?

Comment: The standard seems pretty clear, cppreference not being a normative reference...

Comment: I also lean towards ”no, it is implementation defined”, but would like to get an experts opinion. I have seen a few answers here on SO that make use of (assumed?) unsigned bit field wrap-around, e.g. for getting the max value of an unsigned bit field (`-1` assignment). I wonder if those techniques are actually using implementation defined behavior.

Comment: Note that assignment of `-1` to a bit-field falls in a different category of problem, see http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#6, which is even clearer. These paragraphs have been added in a recent standard, so these questions might be older than the changes in the standard.

Comment: I see, that could explain it, thanks.

Comment: @Holt But was that ever really guaranteed (wrap around) or was that just (possibly illegally) deduced from unsignedness of the BF member? Wondering what else would be meaning full, though.

Comment: @Aconcagua I don't think it was guaranteed, but the old standard was not clear on this point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both [`[expr.pos]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#incr-1) and [`[expr.ass]/6`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#6) agree that integer overflow on a (signed or unsigned) bit-field is implementation defined.

> #### [`[expr.pos]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#incr-1)
>
> [...] If the operand is a bit-field that cannot represent the incremented value, the resulting value of the bit-field is implementation-defined.
>
> #### [`[expr.ass]/6`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#6)
>
> When the left operand of an assignment operator is a bit-field that cannot represent the value of the expression, the resulting value of the bit-field is implementation-defined.

I've fixed the cppreference page. Thank you for noticing.